# Frame rate drops / efficiency problem in three.js

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, webgl

Upon running there is a slow but consistent drop in fps. I have tried to identify the responsible function and it seems to be that:

updatepoints() and rotateTriangle() seem to be the main culprits but it's clear I have misunderstood something or used an inefficient means of calculating something somewhere

Upon further inspection using browser tools it seems to be an array and an object that are filling up the memory which I'm guessing is what is causing the frame drops. 
I have also noticed that the **buffer** in the performance tab for the browser tools is filling up

I know bufferGeometry is the more efficient means of creating objects but I'd still like to know the cause the performance issues

Sorry to just dump code but I feel as though it'll be something obvious. 
Any advice or ways of going about finding the problem and solution would be greatly appreciated

```
//every scene needs these
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;

//links div with canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// What I need are number of particles and the length the curve goes to be uncoupled
// Each part of degree array serves one particles
// If I added a factor so:
// factor * coord *

//creating particles
var particleCount = 360;
var particles = [];
var particles2 = [];
var particles3 = [];
var SPEED = 0.01;

var radians, y, x;
var centerX = 0;
var centerY = 0;
var radius = 231.84;
var pointPositions=[];

var vupdateXvertices, updateYvertices, updateXvertices2, updateYvertices2,
updateXvertices3, updateYvertices3;

var pivot1;
var parent;

var pointsX = [];
var pointsY = [];

var particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x7a7a7a,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.8
});

init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  //setup camera for scene
  //PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far [In terms of camera frustum plane])
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  camera.position.z = 1000;
  //setup renderer for scene (generation of whatever you've made)
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0x31AED1, 1);
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  //OrbitControls(Camera, HTMLDOMElement)
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  // Set to true to enable damping (inertia), which can be used to give a sense
  //of weight to the controls. Default is false.
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
  controls.enableZoom = false;
  console.log("Called");
  fillSceneWithParticles();
  fillSceneWithShapes();
  canvas.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}


function fillSceneWithParticles() {
  var particleGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 32, 32);
  parent = new THREE.Object3D();
  scene.add(parent);

  for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
     particles[i] = new THREE.Mesh( particleGeometry, particleMaterial );
     particles[i].position.x = 0;
     particles[i].position.y = 0;
     particles[i].position.z = (0);

     particles2[i] = new THREE.Mesh( particleGeometry, particleMaterial );
     particles2[i].position.x = (200);
     particles2[i].position.y = (-115.57);
     particles2[i].position.z = (0);

    particles3[i] = new THREE.Mesh( particleGeometry, particleMaterial );
    particles3[i].position.x = (0);
    particles3[i].position.y = (231.84);
    particles3[i].position.z = (0);

    scene.add(particles[i]);
    scene.add(particles2[i]);
    scene.add(particles3[i]);
  }
}

function fillSceneWithShapes() {
  //Add a 2d Triangle W centre = 200, 115.57
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(-200, -115.57, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 200, -115.57, 0 ));
  geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 231.84, 0 ));
  geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -200, -115.57, 0 ));
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 10 } );
  line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
  scene.add(line);
}


function rotateTriangle() {
  var geom = line.geometry.clone();
  geom.applyMatrix(line.matrix);
  updateXvertices = geom.vertices[0].x;
  //The circle that we use to place our points
  var centerX = 0;
  var centerY = 0;
  var radius = 231.84;
  for(var degree = 90; degree < 450; degree++){
    var radians = degree * Math.PI/180;
    var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(radians);
    var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(radians);
    pointsX[degree - 90] = x;
    pointsY[degree - 90] = y;
  }
}

function updatePoints() {
    //link counter with number of degrees initially created
    //These are intialised because V1 = 120 degrees from V0 and V2 = 240 degrees
    var counter = 120;
    var counter2 = 240;
    var zCounter = 0;
    var curveFactor = 1;
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 10 } );
    var secondTriangle = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
      parent.add(particles[i]);
      //Plot points around the circle relative to vertices of triangle
      particles[i].position.x = (pointsX[i]);
      particles[i].position.y = (pointsY[i]);
      particles[i].position.z = zCounter * curveFactor;

      //If array index out of bounds then loop back to the start of array
      //i.e. Go back around the circle relative to the triangle vertices
      parent.add(particles2[i]);
      if (counter == 360) {
        counter = 0;
      }
      particles2[i].position.x = (pointsX[counter]);
      particles2[i].position.y = (pointsY[counter]);
      particles2[i].position.z = zCounter * curveFactor;
      counter++;

      if (counter2 == 360) {
        counter2 = 0;
      }
      parent.add(particles3[i]);
      particles3[i].position.x = (pointsX[counter2]);
      particles3[i].position.y = (pointsY[counter2]);
      particles3[i].position.z = zCounter * curveFactor;
      counter2++;
      zCounter++;
    }
      //Give the second triangle the position of the last particles in array
      secondTriangle.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(particles[particleCount-1].position.x, particles[particleCount-1].position.y, particles[particleCount-1].position.z ));
      secondTriangle.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(particles2[particleCount-1].position.x, particles2[particleCount-1].position.y, particles2[particleCount-1].position.z ));
      secondTriangle.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(particles3[particleCount-1].position.x, particles3[particleCount-1].position.y, particles3[particleCount-1].position.z ));
      secondTriangle.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(particles[particleCount-1].position.x, particles[particleCount-1].position.y, particles[particleCount-1].position.z ));
      line1 = new THREE.Line( secondTriangle, material );
      scene.add(line1);
      parent.add(line1);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    rotateTriangle();
    updatePoints();
    line1.rotation.z -= SPEED *2;
    line.rotation.z -= SPEED *2;
    parent.rotation.z -= SPEED *2;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In retrospect it seems obvious what the problem was.

Since I had geometry.vertices.push inside my animate loop it was continuously pushing new Vectors to a buffer. 
I just had to move the pushing of those vertices and that solved any frame rate and memory problems I was having